# how can get sub nodes in master nodes in C#.net

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

i have a html codes like this :

```
<div class="NewsItemContainer">
  <div class="a1">
   <img class="NewsThumbnail" src="1.jpg">
  </div>
 <div class="NewsLead">
   <span>title</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

and i want get all SubNodes in Nodes.

this is my code :

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\a.htm"); 
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='NewsItemContainer' and @id]");
            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                //HtmlNode h2Node = node.SelectSingleNode("NewsThumbnail");
                foreach (HtmlNode div in node.SelectNodes("//img[@class='NewsThumbnail' and @id]"))
                {
                    HtmlAttribute att = div.Attributes["src"];
                    img = att.Value;
                }
                foreach (HtmlNode div in node.SelectNodes("//span[@class='NewsLead' and @id]"))
                {
                    //HtmlAttribute att = div.InnerText;
                    dsc = div.InnerText;
                }
                MessageBox.Show(img + "\n\r" + dsc);
            }
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Remove `and @id` from the selectnodes statement.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you include the anchor in your `SelectNodes`, `//` will always look from the root node, `.//` looks from the currently selected node.

Plus the span you're lookign for doesn't have the class applied to it, it's parent div has.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\a.htm"); 
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='NewsItemContainer' and @id]");
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode div in node.SelectNodes(".//img[@class='NewsThumbnail']"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute att = div.Attributes["src"];
        img = att.Value;
    }
    foreach (HtmlNode div in node.SelectNodes("./div[@class='NewsLead']/span"))
    {
        //HtmlAttribute att = div.InnerText;
        dsc = div.InnerText;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(img + "\n\r" + dsc);
}
```

Also, if you're looking specifically for an attribute value, you can end your XPath with `@attributename`, like so:

```
foreach (HtmlNode div in node.SelectNodes(".//img[@class='NewsThumbnail']/@src"))
```

That way you can directly use `div.InnerText` to grab the attribute value, without first looking for the `dev.Attributes["src"];`